# Transfer CSV files from SFTP server automatically to sql server as separated tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sftp

My Job is trying to automate a workflow which basically transfers all the CSV files that are stored in the SFTP server folder and fetch them directly to SQL server database in separated tables each file. Is there any way I can complete this task I have been searching on the internet but nothing specifically, also I was considering SSIS packages as an option but they do not have an SFTP server task.

Comment: "Is there any way?" Yes, there are quite a few ways. You've already dismissed the most appropriate method though; you can get SFTP components for SSIS, or download the files via an external method before firing the SSIS package.

Comment: I was try to download a .dll for SFTP task file from one website but I wasn't sure for the security of it, I know there are third parties company that can do that but my company doesn't want to spend money so, I have to find a workaround for this issue.

Comment: Your company needs to understand that your time, and the time of your colleagues, has value too. They pay your salary so it seems like "already spent money" but time spent on this is time they're paying for that you could be doing something else more important. If a component that does the task costs $500 but you spend 15 hours working on a "workaround" and then having to spend 2 hours fixing it when it breaks where the component wouldn't have...well, what's your salary in terms of dollars per hour? I bet the purchase component comes out cheaper.

Answer (score 1):

I would use an SSIS package to handle this due to the SFTP component.

There are a few ways to manage this. You can import an external tool such as a Cozyroc SFTP extension which enables you to set up an SFTP connector. Some of their stuff is chargeable, you would have to check whether it is free for your usage. There may be other similar external tools, I have only used Cozyroc in the past.

You can also write a simple command line batch script using a free windows utility such as winscp. You can then call a script task within SSIS which then calls the batch script.

Once you have execute the SFTP component, you can loop through the downloaded files and upload them to your database server.

Comment: Is there any specific script to get the files from SFTP and insert it directly to SQL server by using WINSCP.

Comment: As I said, these are 2 separate steps. SSIS can manage both. You would first create a script task to run the WinSCP batch script which would fetch the files and bring them to a local space. WINSCP does not have any database connection, so this is solely used to do the download piece. Then, you would create a directory for loop to process each file and run an import into the database. See here for hints as to how to loop through all files in a directory: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2874/loop-through-flat-files-in-sql-server-integration-services/